# Where are CachingManager, CachingMixin, cached_method in Django 2.0?

Tags: python, django

I am upgrading a django project of version 1.4 to djnago version 2.0.there in models.py it has an import path `from caching.base import CachingManager, CachingMixin, cached_method`. But i dont know where to import above in django 2.0 version?

Answer (score 1):

This should still work, but note that they are not provided by Django itself: they are part of `django-cache-machine`.

https://github.com/django-cache-machine/django-cache-machine

Install it with `pip install django-cache-machine`.